# Why is USB HDD slow (reading slower than writing)?

Tags: raspbian, external-hdd, ntfs-3g

Disclaimer: I know there's Raspberry Pi community here, but I don't think it's Pi-specific, more like Raspbian (or Debian?) vs USB HDD vs NTFS, etc.

**TL;DR**: So, I've got a Raspberry Pi 4 with an external USB HDD. Read/write speeds there are quite low, and the most surprising thing for me is that read is actually slower than write! So how could it be and where's the culprit?

**In details**:

- OS

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 5.10.17-v7l+ #1403 SMP Mon Feb 22 11:33:35 GMT 2021 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

- fstab:

```
UUID=1276F80376F7E57F  /mnt/usb_hdd    ntfs-3g    defaults,big_writes,noatime   0   0
```

- hdparm test

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo hdparm -tT /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 Timing cached reads:   1496 MB in  2.00 seconds = 747.81 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 258 MB in  3.01 seconds =  85.60 MB/sec
```

- rsync read

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ rsync --progress -hv /mnt/usb_hdd/Share/Downloads/Games/Civ5.iso ~/Civ5.iso
Civ5.iso
          2.37G 100%   18.90MB/s    0:01:59 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/1)

sent 2.37G bytes  received 35 bytes  19.19M bytes/sec
total size is 2.37G  speedup is 1.00
```

The strange thing is, it starts with ~70MB/s, but almost iimediately drops to ~20 and then deviates between 8 and 25. Very unstable.

- rsync write

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ rsync --progress -hv ~/Civ5.iso /mnt/usb_hdd/Share/Downloads/Civ5.iso
Civ5.iso
          2.37G 100%   39.15MB/s    0:00:57 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/1)

sent 2.37G bytes  received 35 bytes  40.52M bytes/sec
total size is 2.37G  speedup is 1.00
```

This one also starts with ~65MB/s, but gradually slows to ~35. At least not that random as read.

**Questions**

1. Aren't both read **and** write slow in general? Even considering Pi and NTFS - 40MB/s is kind of slow, isn't it? If so - where it the problem?
2. Why is read slower than write?? And why is read speed so unstable over time?

CPU is at ~30% during transfer and there's plenty of memory... Is it "just NTFS"?
Anyway I'll appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, 40MB/s sounds like a bottleneck with USB 2.0. The Pi 4 supports USB 3, but ensure your HDD and cable are USB 3.

Updated with information from the comments:

Also note that your `rsync` involves 2 sides: external HDD and wherever your home is. To remove the second part from the equation try `dd` for just-HDD benchmarking:

- Writing involving filesystem: `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/usb_hdd/blob bs=16M count=100 status=progress oflag=direct`
- Reading from a filesystem: `sudo dd if=/mnt/usb_hdd/blob of=/dev/null bs=16M count=100 status=progress`
- Reading straight from a disk: `sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/null bs=16M count=100 status=progress iflag=direct`

Comment: The HDD is actually a normal laptop HDD in a brand new USB enclosure that promised to support USB 3.0+. I'm pretty sure it does, but how do I make sure?
Anyway, here's result of `sudo lsusb -D /dev/bus/usb/002/002` for it: https://pastebin.com/gTHjLgMt

Comment: @FlasHfromRu yeah, it does appear to be supporting USB 3.0 (look towards the bottom, 5Gbps). Do you get normal read/write speeds on a Windows machine?

Comment: @FlasHfromRu One other thing to check, make sure you've plugged the Pi into one of its USB 3 ports (the blue ones). Not all of them are USB 3. I doubt this is the problem given it detected the device supports USB 3 speeds, though.

Comment: One more thing I would try is to rule out if the bottleneck is filesystem or caching related using the dd utility. This command will *DESTROY* the data on the HDD so make sure it's backed up or use a different harddrive with unimportant data.

Again, this test will destroy the data on the harddrive.

dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/yourhdd bs=16M count=100 status=progress oflag=direct

Comment: Tried on Win10 (same file): read at ~70MB/s, write at ~65MB/s.  
Also tried on my other Mint laptop (same file): read at ~36.5MB/s, write at ~150MB/s O_o
Hm... I guess I need to try some non-NTFS drive :/

Comment: Tried an NTFS-formatted USB stick on the same Mint laptop (still same file): read at ~255MB/s, write at ~150MB/s. Falling back to backing up my HDD, testing with `dd`, then possible fully reformatting it, etc.

Comment: Ok. The dd command I gave you is for a write test. A read test (nondestructive) would be done by the following:  dd if=/dev/yourhdd of=/dev/null bs=16M count=100 status=progress iflag=direct" I probably should have given the nondestructive read test first.... Just make sure "of=/dev/null" for this read test and it won't be destructive.

Comment: So, looks like I've managed to narrow it down to an internal SD card (sic). I.e. tried `dd` reads from an HDD: ~80MB/s (same as on Mint and in Win10). Then tried `dd` writes to an internal SD card: ~20MB/s. So apparently `rsync` HDD -> SD is slow because of an SD card. This makes it Pi-specific - jumping to that community then.  
Do you want to promote your `dd` read/write comments to an answer?

Comment: I've updated you answer according to our discussion here - will accept it once the edit is approved.

Comment: Just in case, here's a link to my R Pi community question, where I've found a solution (and it's not R Pi specific): https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/121991/131260

Comment: You may also play with usb write cache in bios: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=271364 and other info here: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/super-slow-hdd-transfer-speeds-4175679576/

Comment: look here too about usb cache: https://root.nix.dk/en/system-configuration/disable-write-cache-for-usb-devices